# How can I create children of a non-existent parent page in the Wagtail CMS for Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, wagtail, django-cms, wagtail-admin

I want to create children of a page (such as "/questions/example"), without having to create the root page "/questions". Is there a quick way of implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child pages need to be, well, children - so there's no easy way to get around this.

However, if what you're asking is "I want to have `/questions/foo/` without having to have a page accessible at `/questions/`", two options are:

1. add a new QuestionsPage to your project, add it as a child of the root, save as a draft and *don't publish it* - you'll then be able to add child pages to it and publish those, but anyone going to /questions/ will get a 404. This 'works' but isn't super-nice
2. add a StructuralPage (or similar naming) to your project, and override the serve() and serve_preview() methods to redirect to the homepage (or somewhere else) if someone accesses them. You can add child pages to that, etc, as above.

Comment: Option 2 is along the lines of what I was thinking. Thanks!